# MS Graph Calendar API | How to Create an Event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I followed the tutorial link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node

I have 2 files graph.js and calendar.js amongst others.

I want use the post method to create an event.

Following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

and the Get method taught in the tutorial mentioned above, I have created 2 code snippets for each of the files (graph.js and calendar.js)

Graph.js code snippet:

```
  postEvents: async function(accessToken){
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);


    const event1 = {
      subject: "Let's go for lunch",
      body: {
        contentType: "HTML",
        content: "Does noon work for you?"
      },
      start: {
          dateTime: "2020-08-15T12:00:00",
          timeZone: "Pacific Standard Time"
      },
      end: {
          dateTime: "2020-08-15T14:00:00",
          timeZone: "Pacific Standard Time"
      },

      organizer: [
        {
          emailAddress: {
            address:"samanthab@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            name: "Samantha Booth"
          },
          type: "required"
        }
      ],
      allowNewTimeProposals: true
    };


    const events_post = await client
      .api('/me/events')
      .post(event1)
      
    console.log(events_post)
    return events_post; //console.log
    
  }
```

calendar.js code snippet:

```
router.post('/',
  async function(req, res) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      // Redirect unauthenticated requests to home page
      res.redirect('/')
    } else {
      let params = {
        active: { calendar: true } //The active selector is used to select and style the active link
      }; //The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar fields 

      // Get the access token
      var accessToken;
      try {
        accessToken = await tokens.getAccessToken(req);
      } catch (err) {
        req.flash('error_msg', {
          message: 'Could not get access token. Try signing out and signing in again.',
          debug: JSON.stringify(err)
        });
      }

      if (accessToken && accessToken.length > 0) {
        try {
          // post the event
          var event = await graph.postEvents(accessToken);
          params.event = event.value;
        } catch (err) {
          req.flash('error_msg', {
            message: 'Could not post events',
            debug: JSON.stringify(err)
          });
        }
      } else {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Could not get an access token');
      }

      res.render('calendar', params);
    }
  }
);
```

But the event is not created in my outlook calendar.
Can anyone help me figure this out?
I am new to node.js, javascript and concepts of APIs.
I cannot see the log in the console too. (Is this permissions related?)

Ask me if more details are needed.

Thank you in advance.